# In R how to loop through csv files and safe outputs of linear regression in new dataframe?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, linear-regression, plyr

My script and one of the first 3 csv files are can be found in my [Github](https://github.com/MatzeWelp/Conflict_Project.git) folder

I have split a list of NDVI and climate data into small csv. files with 34 years of data each.

Every 34 years should then be split into two parts depending on a conflict year, saved in the same table and a certain time range. But this part of the code works already.

Now I want to control the second part of the list with the climate data of the first part, by using multiple linear regression, which is also done.

I basically need to make a loop to store all the coefficients from every round of the lm function of one csv. file in a new list.

I know that I can use lapply to loop and get the output as a list. But there are some missing parts to actually loop through the csv. files.

```
#load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)


file_paths <- fs::dir_ls("E:\\PYTHON_ST\\breakCSV_PYTHON\\AIM_2_regions\\Afghanistan")
file_paths

#create empty list and fill with file paths and loop through them
file_contents <- list()
for (i in seq_along(file_paths)) { #seq_along for vectors (list of file paths is a vector)
  file_contents[[i]] <- read_csv(file = file_paths[[i]])
                  
                for (i in seq_len(file_contents[[i]])){ # redundant?
                  
                 # do all the following steps in every file                                        
                 
                 # Step 1) 
                 # Define years to divide table
                 
                 #select conflict year in df 
                 ConflictYear = file_contents[[i]][1,9]
                 ConflictYear
                 
                 # select Start year of regression in df
                 SlopeYears = file_contents[[i]][1,7] #to get slope years (e.g.17)
                 BCStartYear = ConflictYear-SlopeYears #to get start year for regression
                 BCStartYear
                 
                 #End year of regression
                 ACEndYear = ConflictYear+(SlopeYears-1) # -1 because the conflict year is included
                 ACEndYear
                 
                 
                 # Step 2
                 
                 #select needed rows from df
                 #no headers but row numbers. NDVI.Year = [r1-r34,c2]
                 NDVI.Year <- file_contents[[i]][1:34,2]
                 NDVI <- file_contents[[i]][1:34,21]
                 T.annual.max <- file_contents[[i]][1:34,19]
                 Prec.annual.max <- file_contents[[i]][1:34,20]
                 soilM.annual.max <- file_contents[[i]][1:34,18]
                 
                 #Define BeforeConf and AfterConf depending on Slope Year number and Conflict Years
                 #Go through NDVI.Year till Conflict.Year (-1 year) since the conflict year is not included in bc
                 BeforeConf1 <- file_contents[[i]][ which(file_contents[[i]]$NDVI.Year >= BCStartYear & file_contents[[i]]$NDVI.Year < ConflictYear),] #eg. 1982 to 1999
                 BeforeConf2 <-  c(NDVI.Year, NDVI, T.annual.max, Prec.annual.max, soilM.annual.max) #which columns to include
                 BeforeConf <- BeforeConf1[BeforeConf2] #create table
                 
                 AfterConf1 <- myFiles[ which(file_contents[[i]]$NDVI.Year >= ConflictYear & file_contents[[i]]$NDVI.Year <= ACEndYear),] #eg. 1999 to 2015
                 AfterConf2 <-  c(NDVI.Year, NDVI, T.annual.max, Prec.annual.max, soilM.annual.max)
                 AfterConf <- AfterConf1[AfterConf2]
                 
                 #Step 3)a)
                 #create empty list, to fill with coefficient results from each model results for each csv file and safe in new list
                 
                 #Create an empty df for the output coefficients
                 names <- c("(Intercept)","BeforeConf$T.annual.max","BeforeConf$Prec.annual.max","BeforeConf$soilM.annual.max")
                 coef_df <- data.frame()
                 for (k in names) coef_df[[k]] <- as.character() 
                 
                 #Apply Multiple Linear Regression
                 plyrFunc <- function(x){
                   model <- lm(NDVI ~ T.annual.max + Prec.annual.max + soilM.annual.max, data = BeforeConf)
                   return(summary(model)$coefficients[1,1:4])
                 }
                 
                 coef_df <- ddply(BeforeConf, .(), x)
                 coef_DF
    }}
```

Comment: *there are some missing parts* is not quite clear. Please explain specifically what does not work in your long code block.

Comment: So the code worked before for only one csv file. The main issue is to change it to loop through the list of csv files and do the tasks for all the files. I changed the previous file name to 'file_contents[[i]]' for that purpose. But I don't know if it works like that. 
The second problem is to store the coefficients in a new df. Does that have to be inside the loop? It's the same problem, it worked for a single file, but I don't know how to change it to a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have code working for a single CSV, consider separating process and loop. Specifically:

1. Create a function that receives a single csv path as input parameter and does everything you need for a *single* file.

   ```r
   get_coeffs <- function(csv_path) {
     df <- read.csv(csv_path)

     ### Step 1
     # select conflict year, start year, and end year in df 
     ConflictYear <- df[1,9]
     SlopeYears <- df[1,7]                       # to get slope years (e.g.17)
     BCStartYear <- ConflictYear - SlopeYears    # to get start year for regression
     ACEndYear <- ConflictYear + (SlopeYears-1)  # -1 because the conflict year is included

     ### Step 2
     # select needed rows from df
     #no headers but row numbers. NDVI.Year = [r1-r34,c2]
     NDVI.Year <- df[1:34, 2]
     NDVI <- df[1:34, 21]
     T.annual.max <- df[1:34, 19]
     Prec.annual.max <- df[1:34, 20]
     soilM.annual.max <- df[1:34, 18]

     # Define BeforeConf and AfterConf depending on Slope Year number and Conflict Years
     # Go through NDVI.Year till Conflict.Year (-1 year) since the conflict year is not included in bc
     BeforeConf1 <- df[ which(df$NDVI.Year >= BCStartYear & df$NDVI.Year < ConflictYear),]
     BeforeConf2 <- c(NDVI.Year, NDVI, T.annual.max, Prec.annual.max, soilM.annual.max)
     BeforeConf  <- BeforeConf1[BeforeConf2] #create table

     AfterConf1 <- myFiles[ which(df$NDVI.Year >= ConflictYear & df$NDVI.Year <= ACEndYear),]
     AfterConf2 <- c(NDVI.Year, NDVI, T.annual.max, Prec.annual.max, soilM.annual.max)
     AfterConf  <- AfterConf1[AfterConf2]

     ### Step 3
     tryCatch({
         # Run model and return coefficients
         model <- lm(NDVI ~ T.annual.max + Prec.annual.max + soilM.annual.max, data = BeforeConf) 
         return(summary(model)$coefficients[1,1:4])
     }, error = function(e) {
         print(e)
         return(rep(NA, 4))
     })
   }
   ```
2. Loop through csv paths, passing each file into your function, building a list of results which you can handle with `lapply` for list return or `sapply` (or `vapply` that specifies length and type) for simplified return such as vector, matrix/array if applicable.

   ```r
   mypath <- "E:\\PYTHON_ST\\breakCSV_PYTHON\\AIM_2_regions\\Afghanistan"
   file_paths <- list.files(pattern=".csv", path=mypath)

   # LIST RETURN
   result_list <- lapply(file_paths, get_coeffs)

   # MATRIX RETURN
   results_matrix <- sapply(file_paths, get_coeffs)
   results_matrix <- vapply(file_paths, get_coeffs, numeric(4))
   ```

Comment: I adjusted the code with your comments. For one file it is working. But when I call the results_matrix function then it returns the same four coefficients values for all the files instead of calculating new coefficients for every file.  I added this: 
```file_contents <- list()
for (i in seq_along(file_paths)) { #seq_along for vectors (list of file paths is a vector)
  file_contents[[i]] <- read_csv(file = file_paths[[i]])}```

It didn't work. But I think it only adds the file paths to the repeating coefficients instead of actually using the data inside the files.

Comment: I believe you kept your code of `file_contents[[i]]` within the function which should have been replaced with `df` (first line assignment). To be explicit I edited with fuller code instead of abbreviated `...` which may need testing. Try again as *apply* functions should effectively iterate through files.

Comment: I changed the script now with your adjustments and it seems to work. However, I get this `Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases` error message now. It could be that there are zeros or missing data in my code. I changed the formula by adding `na.action=na.exclude`. `model <- lm(NDVI ~ T + Prec + soilM, data = BeforeConf, na.action=na.exclude)` but it is still occurring. Do you have an idea how to solve it otherwise?

Comment: Likely that is a data issue as model cannot be run. See update wrapping your `lm` run in `tryCatch`. If it errs out, error will be printed and `NA` will be generated in final matrix for the CSV.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! I have a data table for the coefs now and the NA are also printed so I can exclude them. 
But I realized that for my analysis I need another step inside the loop. Instead of printing them in a list. I need the ceofs of every round, put them in a formula and calculate a new NDVI value with them. These new values need to be printed or put in a new column. Should I post this as a new question if I don't get it done? This is the error rn:
`Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Not quite clear what you attempted. But you can use the vector of coefficients like any other set of numbers at the end any way you need. What is the formula? In fact, you can add a new column to `df` and return `df` where output will be a list of data frames.

Comment: My aim is to use the coefficients and put them in the formula to receive new NDVI values which are controlled with the climate data. It's basically the same formula as above but without lm:
`NDVI_AfterConf_Climate <- summary(model)$coefficients[1,1] + ((summary(model)$coefficients[2,1])*AfterConf$T) +  ((summary(model)$coefficients[3,1])*AfterConf$Prec) + ((summary(model)$coefficients[4,1])*AfterConf$soilM)`

But you are right, maybe instead of doing that directly in the first loop, I could use the coeffiecnts list, loop through them, to put the values in the formula and then add as column.